# Javascript: Does modifying scrollTop/scrollLeft trigger browser reflow?

Tags: javascript, performance, scrollbar, reflow

I'm wondering if animating the scrollbars with Javascript triggers browser reflow.

Any difference across different browser implementations?

window.pageXOffset & window.pageYOffset
document.documentElement.scrollLeft & document.documentElement.scrollTop
document.body.scrollLeft & document.body.scrollTop

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I dug in deeper and found this link which says it does cause reflow:
http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

I also tested it and modifying scrollTop and scrollLeft both trigger reflow (in Firefox at least).

Heh sorry for answering my own question, but hopefully this info is useful for someone :).

Comment: Nice article, thanks. And sorry I was too hasty to answer this question without thorough research.

Comment: yes, triggers reflow, according to my test and the comprehensive list from Paul Irish: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/when-does-reflow-happen-in-a-dom-environment), no.