# Javascripts Object member access

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I'm wondering about access times on object members. More precisely, I'm benchmarking access times on the `window` object. I believe I can explain most behavior here on my own, but I'd feel better to hear some comments.

Usecase: Different access times on different propertys ?

I'm benchmarking on Firefox 3.6.8 (windows), the simple measuring code looks like:

```
var loop = 100000;

console.time('bench');
while(loop--){
   if(window.JSON)
      var foo = 0;
}
console.timeEnd('bench');
```

The first strange thing is, it makes a different which property I'm looking up. For instance, `window.JSON` seems to be faster to access, than `window.localStorage`. There are other propertys/methods which can get accessed even faster.
Since there is no specification or defination within in the the [ECMA-262 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), which order keys must have in an object, I guess each browser vendor implements it's own logic in which order `keys` are stored in memory.
Could this be an explanation for this behavior? Like, `JSON` is one of the very first keys and `location` is more at the end? (In my test environment at least)

**--**

Another thing I noticed is, that calling `if(JSON)` is slightly faster than `if(window.JSON)`. If we forget about that you always should do the second call because of possible reference errors, those calls should have the same access time. I'm aware of ECMAscripts behavior on `nested member lookups` (**A nested member will cause the Javascript engine to go through the object member resolution, each time a dot is encountered**), so `window.location.href` must be slower than `location.href`, but in this case.. is there a difference between `JSON` and `window.JSON` ?

To end this, the fastest way to know whether or not the `window` object owns a specific property/method is to use the `IN` operator. That is about 10 times faster for the above examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first strange thing you notice might have to do about how [*host objects*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#hostObject) are implemented by the browser.

`localStorage` is a *host object*, provided by the environment, `JSON` on the other hand, is a [*built-in object*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#builtInObject) provided by ECMAScript.

Try to resolve another built-in's and you will get more or less the same results than with `JSON`.

Now, the difference about `JSON` vs `window.JSON`:

`window` is just a property on the global object that points to itself, when you access the `window` identifier the name resolution process takes place to find it.

Basically referencing:

```
JSON;
```

Involves only one identifier lookup (in the scope chain), and:

```
window.JSON;
```

Involves an identifier lookup (`window`) and a property lookup (`window.JSON`).

Comment: Does the `host object` concept also explain, why the access on `window.outerWidth` takes three times as long as the access on `window.setTimeout` (for instance) ?

Comment: @jAndy, both, `outerWidth` and `setTimeout` can be considered as host-objects, `outerWidth` is presumably implemented as an *accessor property*, when you access it a getter function is executed, and since it's related to the DOM layout, the current value (the measurement in pixels) must be recalculated, causing a **reflow** (See: [1](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3#reflow) [2](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/) ), while `setTimeout` is simply a function object.

Comment: pretty interesting, I forgot about the fact that reflows can happen even on accessing a computed style. Anyways, in Nicholas blog, Dean Edwards is doubting that. But then again, if my measuring results are true, it looks like an ultimate fact for a reflow on accessing `outerWidth` (for instance). Might be browser dependent too? Thanks anyway!