# Efficient way to access members of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, performance

My question somehow relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631158/javascripts-object-member-access), but it still involves some key differences.

So here it is, I have following code;

```
for(var i = 0; i < someObj.children[1].listItems.length; i++)
{
    doSomething(someObj.children[1].listItems[i]);

    console.log(someObj.children[1].listItems[i]);
}
```

vs.

```
var i = 0,
    itemLength = someObj.children[1].listItems.length,
    item;

for(; i < itemLength; i++)
{
    item = someObj.children[1].listItems[i];
    doSomething(item);

    console.log(item);
}
```

Now this is a *very* small exemplary part of code I deal with in an enterprise webapp made in **ExtJS**. Now here in above code, second example is clearly more readable and clean compared to first one.
**But is there any performance gain involved when I reduce number of object lookups in similar way?**

I'm asking this for a scenario where there'll be a lot more code within the loop accessing members deep within the object and iteration itself would be happening ~1000 times, and browser varies from IE8 to Latest Chrome.

Comment: performance gain is negligible

Comment: You can try creating a test at jsperf.com. (Here's an example similar to what you're asking: http://jsperf.com/iterate-object-vs-loop-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There won't be a noticeable difference, but for performance and readability, and the fact that it does look like a live nodeList, it should probably be iterated in reverse if you're going to change it :

```
var elems = someObj.children[1].listItems;

for(var i = elems.length; i--;) {
    doSomething(elems[i]);
    console.log(elems[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think I like your loop better than mine.  Thought the `i--` would miss the `i === 0` case, but I was wrong.  Also, it winks at me.

Comment: Thank's a lot, especially for reversed iteration thing, totally new for me!

Answer (score 1):

Performance gain will depend on how large the list is.

Caching the length is typically better (your second case), because `someObj.children[1].listItems.length` is not evaluated every time through the loop, as it is in your first case.

If order doesn't matter, I like to loop like this:

```
var i;

for( i = array.length; --i >= 0; ){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caching object property lookup will result in a performance gain, but the extent of it is based on iterations and depth of the lookups. When your JS engine evaluates something like `object.a.b.c.d`, there is more work involved than just evaluating `d`.  You can make your second case more efficient by caching additional property lookups outside the loop:

```
var i = 0,
    items = someObj.children[1].listItems,
    itemLength = items.length,
    item;

for(; i < itemLength; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    doSomething(item);

    console.log(item);
}
```

The best way to tell, of course, is a jsperf