# Firefox 4 doesn't render partial pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, flush

I have [an ASP.NET MVC page](http://svick.org/TrackProtections.aspx/List?title=Iranian+Azerbaijanis&reverse=false) which contains a table, where every row takes some time to load. So I'm calling `Response.Flush()` after every row is rendered.

IE9 behaves the way it should: displays rows one by one. FF4 on the other hand, displays the page only when it finished loading completely, even though I can see in FireBug's Network tab that the rows are being received one by one.

Is there something I could be doing wrong on the server-side? If not, is there something I can do to my Firefox, so that it displays the page the way I want?

Comment: Unfortunately, "fixing" your firefox (if it's an option) won't help a client with theirs ;-) Does FF wait for the *page* to finish or for the *table* to finish?

Comment: @pst, yeah, I realize that. I think it's waiting for the whole page to finish, because it doesn't display anything until the end. The only indication that anything even was received is that it displays the `<title>`.

Comment: You probably want to google "incremental reflow".

Comment: @MSalters, from the pages I found, it seems this should be working as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using AJAX to fill the table. Maybe a row per call, maybe whole set at once.

Answer (score 1):

Consider closing your document with `</html>` and add the extra rows in script; `<script>` tags may (in practice) follow `</html>`. Not a real AJAX solution, not strictly correct, but potentially a lot easier on your serverside.

A similar, but more correct solution would be to insert the script just before the `</body>`.

See also [When does reflow happen in a DOM environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/when-does-reflow-happen-in-a-dom-environment)