# Is there some promise on browser rendering success?

Tags: javascript, dom, promise, render, render-html

I want to insert some html asynchronously into the page, and then execute some javascript codes correlated with the inserted DOM.

This kind of endeavour always fail because DOM rendering in the browser takes much more time than the next javascript codes to execute.

I have met with such problem before and have asked a question, but nobody answered. It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935005/whats-going-on-with-dom-after-orientationchange-event

So, can I get a promise or attach some callback function?

Codes here:

```
var bubble = function bubble(type,content){
    var myScroll, temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML=content;
    temp.className=type==='time'?'time':'bubble '+type;
    document.getElementsByClassName('dialogue')[0].appendChild(temp);
    if(type==='reply')myScroll = new IScroll('.dlg-wrapper', { mouseWheel: true });
};
```

Comment: How did you do this asynchronously inserting and how did you respond to it. Please show your code.

Comment: @GolezTrol Codes added. In fact it's always like this whatever the codes are, as long as it manipulates the DOM so that causes rerendering and then accesses them immediately in javascript. You can see the same thing in the linked question I mentioned.

Comment: So which part of this code is being called too early? I see nothing asynchronous happening here.

Comment: Of course the code immediately after DOM inserting.

Comment: @GolezTrol Well, I think you don't understand browser behaviors very well.

Comment: The rendering after inserting is asynchronous.

Comment: No it's not. It's just postponed until your script is idle. That's also what the answer [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838003/synchronous-asynchronous-nature-of-browser-rendering-and-javascript-execution) suggest, which by the way also suggest using `setTimeout` as a solution.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm sorry. It's true that the problem I said can't be clearly seen in my code. I met such problem because IScroll needs to know `.dialogue`'s height to decide how to enable scrolling inside `.dlg-wrapper`. I appended a child dom into `.dialogue` so that it's height will be higher. But scrolling inside `.dlg-wrapper` initialized before the height change.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not such an event one could listen. But you can do something normally used for animation. To keep animations run smoothly at a high rate it nessesary to batch all DOM Access as [FastDom.js](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom) tries to abstract away.

All in all, the weapon of choice should be `requestAnimationFrame()` to schuedle your DOM access to a Frame, where the browser has updated the DOM.

In your case, `new IScroll(...)` needs to be schuedled until `querySelector('.dlg-wrapper')` actually returns the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rendering is asynchronous, but it is triggered by a message that is only processed after the script ended.

But you said *"and then execute some javascript codes correlated with the inserted DOM."*. I don't see that happening in your code.

Anyway, if you use `setTimeout(callback, 0)` you can do the post-processing in callback. `setTimeout` is also controlled by that message queue, so after the code that modified the DOM is finished, the browser will first process the redraw message (because that is first in the message queue), and only then call the callback.

Comment: setTimeout won't work. I tried here in this problem, and I have also tried in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935005/whats-going-on-with-dom-after-orientationchange-event

Comment: At least, it's not synchronous, is it? Did I misunderstand the concepts?

Comment: It's message based. Changing the DOM will queue a message, which is processed not asynchronously to your script, but after the script has ended. So yes, you misunderstood the concepts.