# Get width of element without doing a reflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I need to get the size of many small `<div>`-Elements, before inserting them into the DOM.

Currently, I'm adding them temporarily, getting their `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, then I remove them again:

```
document.body.appendChild(child);
size = [child.offsetWidth, child.offsetHeight]
document.body.removeChild(child);
```

The problem is, that this is super-slow, because it triggers a reflow for every `<div>` being measured.

Do you have any idea how to speed this up?

Comment: could you use a dummy div in memory to contain the new element? also, [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393141/is-it-possible-to-access-the-current-scaling-factor-of-a-width-element-by-java) Q/A

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why you feel the need to do this? You say "many small divs" so I assume they're all different sizes. What is the size based on?

Comment: The size is based on the content (text). All texts are different.

Comment: keep one `<div>` far off-screen, populate that element with the content, retrieve its dimensions, clear it out for the next content and continue until all sizes are retrieved? I suspect that this will still trigger a reflow, however, but it might not be quite so slow - or CPU intensive - since you're not creating and recreating new `<div>` elements time after time.

Comment: hrm, seems my assumptions were wrong -- but it might be worth checking if display: none; will cause a reflow -- it isn't in the render tree. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction

Comment: Changing the `display`-property to `none` will collapse the element, hence `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` will be 0.

Comment: I like the suggestion from the Wendy's guy in that case. You saying "div" lead me to believe they'd be block elements.

Comment: You can't prevent a reflow. The reflow Do exactly what you want : measure stuff in your page. 
If you have lots of elements, it's probably better to add all your divs to the page, then measure them. The browser will make one big reflow for the first div. But the performance gain may depend on the number of divs.

Answer (score 1):

In case of someone is still looking for the answer (as I was) of how to get the bounds of the with no reflow, use `IntersectionObserver` and its `boundingClientRect` interface.

You can read more here https://toruskit.com/blog/how-to-get-element-bounds-without-reflow

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)