# Idont understand how setTimeout(fn,0) in javascript works

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I'm having problems understanding why code below doesn't behave as I would expect it to. I would expect it to:

1. display aaa in yellow border,
2. then block UI for short time (`for` loop)
3. then display "nothing" in pink border

When I replace setTimeout(aaa,0) with setTimeout(aaa,100) it works fine every time but shouldn't the setTimeout(aaa,0) put my aaa function in the queue and allow browser to do the redraw before aa is run? Iwould expect it to follow steps 1-3 every time yet obviously I'm missing something. It seems to behave this way every second run only.

Code is below and I've created fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dDJ8L/

HTML

```
<div id="aaa" style="border: 1px solid green">aaa</div>
```

Javascript

```
div = document.getElementById("aaa");

div.style.border = "1px solid red";


function aaa() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        div.innerHTML = i;
    }
    div.innerHTML = "nothing";
    div.style.border = "1px solid pink";
}

div.style.border = "1px solid blue";
setTimeout(aaa, 0);
div.style.border = "1px solid yellow";
```

Comment: To me it works as intended. What are you seeing that you don't expect?

Comment: I think the issue is whether the browser redraws the display when it returns to the event loop and there's already a timer function waiting to run. Maybe some browsers run the function first, others redraw first. In Chrome, I see what you expect.

Comment: @bfavaretto it seems to work every second time only, I don't understand why

Comment: I run it in FF and it works as expected every time so border becomes yellow, execution ends, timeout fires and enters the loop, it runs and then pink. Chrome redraws yellow frame after execution ends but only every second time. I run Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m on Vista. Obviously its one of those browser dependent cases

Answer (score 2):

.setTimeout() puts it in the queue at the end. It is running after the border is set to yellow so it comes up as pink.

Comment: If you use jQuery you could use the .queue method to handle how/when things are called. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

Answer (score 1):

Your code does 1, then 2, then 3. Lets go step by step through it.

1. display aaa in yellow border

```
div.style.border = "1px solid red";
div.style.border = "1px solid blue";//overwrites red
div.style.border = "1px solid yellow";//overwrites blue
```

The last definition takes precedence here. It will cause the div to have a yellow border. The default text in the html was "aaa".

2. then block UI for short time (for loop)

```
setTimeout(aaa, 0);
function aaa() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    div.innerHTML = i;
 }
 ...
}
```

When `0` is used for the `setTimeout` then it is going to use the smallest interval allowed *by the browser*. For the most part, you can assume this will be anywhere from 4-10 milliseconds. So really, the code there should read `setTimeout(aaa, 10);`. Either way, the "short time" is **really** short here and so you do not see the pause from the timeout. Moreover, the timeout is going to cause the function call to occur *asynchronously* as opposed to sequentially. This means that the rest of the code will execute before the function `aaa` will execute. The for loop over 1,000,000 iterations is actually very very fast (since there are no changes after the first loop some engines like V8 will actually optimize the rest of the loop ideally).

3. then display "nothing" in pink border

```
div.innerHTML = "nothing";
div.style.border = "1px solid pink";
```

This code is at the end of the function `aaa` and does display the final result with a pink border which says "nothing".

This is a fiddle of the code in its entirety: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dDJ8L/)