# Poll phase in NodeJS event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I was going through node [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) for event loop and I got very confused.
It says -

```
timers: this phase executes callbacks scheduled by setTimeout() and 
setInterval().
I/O callbacks: executes almost all callbacks with the exception of close callbacks, the ones scheduled by timers, and setImmediate().
idle, prepare: only used internally.
poll: retrieve new I/O events; node will block here when appropriate.
check: setImmediate() callbacks are invoked here.
close callbacks: e.g. socket.on('close', ...).
```

Then in detailed poll phase, they say that it executes timers scheduled with timer and also process i/o events in poll queue. My confusion is taht we already have timer phase and i/o callback phase for those callbacks, then what is the work done by poll phase. It also says that thread may sleep in poll phase but I don't get it properly.
My questions are-

1. Why poll phase is executing scripts for timers and i/o(s) when we already have timer and i/o callback phase ?
2. Is it like  poll phase executes callbacks on behalf of timer and i/o callback phase and timer and callback phase is only for internal processing no callbacks are executed in this phase ?
3. Where can we place promises in this loop ? Earlier I thought that promises can be thought simply as callbacks and we can treat them like callbacks only, but in [this](http://www.dev-conferences.com/en/talks/morning-keynote-everything-you-need-to-know-about-nodejs-event-loop-bert-belder-ibm/5276) video, he says that promises goes into an internal event loop, but does not talk in detail.

I am very confused at this point. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The `poll` phase boils down to an asynchronous I/O wait. Libuv will use different APIs depending on the OS but they all generally have the same pattern. I'm going to use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) as an example.

The `poll` is basically a system call like this:

```
select(maxNumberOfIO, readableIOList, writableIOList, errorIOList, timeout);
```

This function blocks. If no `timeout` value is specified it blocks **forever**.

The result is that node.js will not be able to execute any javascript as long as there is no I/O activity. This obviously makes it impossible to execute time-based callbacks like `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Therefore, what node needs to do before calling such a function is to calculate what value to pass as `timeout`. It generally does this by going through the list of all timers and figure out the shortest amount of time it can wait for I/O (the next nearest timer) and use that as the timeout value. It basically processes all the timers but not to execute their callbacks, it does it to figure out the wait time.

Comment: What if we are blocked "forever" but some I/O callback schedules a function with `setImmediately`? Would this waiting be interrupted?

Comment: There is no interrupting the program execution. The C interrupt handler (which is part of the OS - Windows, Linux or MacOS) will register an OS event which can be read later by javascript (node.js, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge etc.) but the javascript engine itself is not interruptable. The interpreter will simply execute forever before attempting to check the OS event and since forever never ends the `setImmediately` callback never gets executed

Comment: I've written much more detailed answers related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855352/how-in-general-does-node-js-handle-10-000-concurrent-requests/34857298#34857298 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262054/is-there-any-other-way-to-implement-a-listening-function-without-an-infinite-w/61826079#61826079

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677852/node-js-single-thread-mechanism/65678349#65678349 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970655/is-my-understanding-of-asynchronous-operations-correct/62974386#62974386 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616477/does-javascript-process-using-an-elastic-racetrack-algorithm/19620041#19620041 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165375/do-timers-run-on-their-own-threads-in-node-js/62165526#62165526

Comment: And a few more I've probably forgotten. If you need code to execute on time regardless then you need a thread. For browsers use web workers and for node.js use worker threads

Comment: Your answers really cleared up a lot for me. But still I have a little misunderstanding. When `select()` function returns because some I/O event takes place the callback can in this point of time schedule some `setImmediate()` function. In this case does `libuv` recalculate its timeout (set it at 0) before call `select()` again?

Comment: I asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869806/can-i-o-callback-setimmediate-interrupt-waiting-for-other-i-o-notifications In any case, thank you for your thoroughgoing answers.

Comment: @Mergasov Yes. Having actually implemented setTimeout and setInterval type functions for the Ferite programming language (http://ferite.sourceforge.net) that's exactly how I did it. Except you don't need to calculate timeout for setImmediate callbacks - you just call all of them at the end of script execution before calling `select()`. For setTimeout and setInterval you keep a list of times when the callbacks needs to be called and calculate the next timeout

Comment: @slebetman - suppose there are 5 callback in timer queue, 5 are not timed out yet,  and now event loop is in poll phase , poll queue was empty and it is waiting for new events now 1 timer has timed out, so event loop will directly jump to timer phase or first go to next phase, next phase and 1 cycle completed, now go to timer phase of new cycle ??

Comment: @slebetman - also different question - if there are 5000 timers in timer queue, will event loop be stuck for too much time in timer phase or move to next phase after say executing some 200 timers (as max limit ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs has 5 major phases.
1) timers phase.
2) pending call back phase.
3) poll phase
4) check (set immediate).
5) close

Answer to your questions.
1)The call backs to timers and check phase are executed in their respective phases and not in poll phase.

2)All the I/o related call backs and other are executed in the poll phase. The pending call back phase is only for system level callbacks like tcp errors, none of our concern

3)After each phase, node js has an internal event loop which resolves all the process.nextTick callbacks, and another smaller event loop which executes the resolved promises then callbacks i.e Promise.resolve.then() callbacks.

Comment: "2)All the I/o related call backs and other are executed in the poll phase." - what is "other" here that you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading about that myself.  As far as the timers are concerned the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) about the event loop gives a decent answer in the form of an example.  Say a setTimeout timer is set to trigger after 100ms but an I/O process is in progress (in the polling phase) and requires more than 100ms to execute, say 150ms.  Once it is finished the polling phase will then wrap back to the timer phase and execute the setTimeout later than the expected 100ms, at 150ms.

Hope that helps answer how the polling phase relates to the timer phase.  In essence the polling phase, as I understand it, can 'make the decision' to run the timer phase again if necessary.

Comment: found this discussion on reddit that seems illuminating still trying to fully grok it https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/75m6cx/libuv_how_is_the_poll_phase_differentiated_from/?st=ja484wrx&sh=4c279c13