# Can a setImmediate() function scheduled in an I/O callback recalculate timeout for other I/O notifications?

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

There is the `poll` stage of the Node js's event loop. Its aim is to blockingly wait for I/O notifications and then execute needed callbacks. A timeout time of the waiting is calculated before entering this stage. If there were operations scheduled through `setImmediate` than the timeout is set at 0, if timers took place than timeout is set with a view of them and if there are no such impediments the blocking would continue "forever".

What will happen if the timeout is initially set at "infinity" and an I/O callback schedules a function with `setImmediate` or `setInterval`? Would the timeout be recalculated immediately or only after the I/O queue got empty (in a next loop iteration)?

So if we wait for two launched asynchronous opearations with callbacks `A` and `B` and after receiving an I/O notification `A` is executed and it in turn schedules some `C` function with `setImmediate` what the function would execute first `B` or `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for some of the more common asynchronous API with timer support (eg. the `select()` or `kqueue()` system call) a timer value of zero (`0`) represents the value of **infinity** so you cannot implement a function like `setImmediate()` or `nextTick()` the usual way by calculating the next timeout value and calling the asynchronous API. Instead all `setImmediate()` or `nextTick()` callbacks **must** be called synchronously before calling the asynchronous API.

Therefore, since `C` is a callback to `setImmediate()` it will be called before we re-enter the event loop to wait for `B` to fire.

So if `A` and **only** a gets triggered then the sequence of function calls would be: `A` and `C`.

But if `A` and `B` happens at the same time the sequence of function calls would be: `A`, `B`, `C`.

Note that I said `A` and `C` and not `A`, `C`, `B` because we didn't say `B` gets triggered. For all I know `B` will only get triggered 8 months from now or even never.

But if `A` gets triggered and 1 millisecond later `B` happens then the sequence of function calls would be: `A`, `C`, `B`

---

Is it possible for two events to happen in the same event loop? Generally yes. If it's network I/O it is unlikely because IP packets are serialized but it can still happen especially if you have a machine with multiple network cards. If it's graphical events like DOM updates then two things happening in the same event loop is quite common eg: both page resize and content reflow can happen at the same time especially with responsive CSS using media query where page resize can trigger content reflow.