# Would like help figuring out the best way to watch for changes to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Jquery-Mutation Summary https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/
"a JavaScript library that makes observing changes to the DOM fast, easy and safe"

It can be found here: https://github.com/joelpurra/jquery-mutation-summary

Here's an example of it at work:
http://joelpurra.github.io/jquery-mutation-summary/example/demo.html

All I want to do is call a function when there's changes to content within an element such as a div with an id "MyDiv"

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong? There is no alert message as my function that's being called in this example is suppose to display once changes are observed.

```
<script src="http://joelpurra.github.io/jquery-mutation-summary/lib/mutation-summary  /src/mutation-summary.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://joelpurra.github.io/jquery-mutation-summary/src/jquery.mutation- summary.js"></script>

<script>
function MyFunction(){
alert('changes have been made');
}

// This code won't be executed until jQuery has been loaded.
$(function() {
var $ChangeThere = $("#MyDiv")
// The callback in this case will only print the result
// Connect mutation-summary
$ChangeThere.mutationSummary("connect", callback, [{
    all: true
}]);

// Disconnect when done listening
//$ChangeThere.mutationSummary("disconnect");




function callback(summaries) {

    MyFunction();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: you havent defined `MyFunction()` anywhere

Comment: It is defined in my code but I'll add it

Comment: It looks like you're using it correctly. What problem are you having?

Comment: My problem is, there's no alert message. It's not calling my function when changes are made.

Comment: You have spaces in your `src` URLs. Is that in the original code or a copying error.

Comment: After I fix the URLs, your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3nd7K/4/

Comment: You know what the issue is, it's the element I'm trying to check for changes. It's an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of Firefox, a `mozAfterPaint` event exists, but there's obvious compatibility problems with that, so I'd suggest checking for the various things that cause reflows by adding a check into an abstracted version of each cause. A list of causes and some other information can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/when-does-reflow-happen-in-a-dom-environment) SO