# preventing screen redraw on resizing

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

Is there a way to prevent the redrawing of the screen while resizing a responsive website?

I want to have a responsive website, but I don't like the cheap animations that are involved when resizing the screen (media breaks, instant disappears, text wraps (really ugly))

I hope there is a way to tell the browser to redraw the screen only when resizing has stopped or some similar solution..

Is there?

Comment: Can you give some examples, I don't get why media doesn't do the trick

Comment: Yes please give more examples. Also, are you using Twitter Bootstrap? (or anything else like that). It handles responsive design pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you change the size of any DOM element, including the `body`, all browsers "reflow" (i.e. redraw) the page. Even when you include an `img` element without an explicit size, the page  will reflow when an image is loaded.

You may read more details here:

[When does reflow happen in a DOM environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/when-does-reflow-happen-in-a-dom-environment)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent redrawing set a timer something like that might help

```
    var timeoutHandler;
    var startet=false
    resize=function(){
           clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
           if(!startet){
              startet=true;
             //get body pixel width
             //get body pixel height;
             //save css width value 
             //save css height value
             //set body width= width pixel value;
             //set body height= height pixel value;
           }
            timeoutHandler=setTimeout(function(){
                 //restore css values
                  startet=false;
            },100);

    }
```