# When firefox recalculates positions of elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I change some properties of some dom element in a function using javascript does the browser recalculate new position of elements immediately, before the function will be finished? That is, if I made one element invisible like `obj.style.display = 'none'` and read in the same functions properties of another element will they be recalculated?

Comment: They will recalculated once the function is finished.

Comment: Everything is calculated when Javascript returns to the main event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is slightly more perverse than that. DOM updates in modern browsers are cached before being flushed at a certain interval... BUT, by inquiring into the DOM's state, you force the browser to perform the reflow there and then. It's part of the expected behaviour.

See an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510213/when-does-reflow-happen-in-a-dom-environment)

So, if you want to defer the reflow, maybe get whatever computed values you require first. Otherwise, you should be ok. However, as it's part of a "standard", you may find implementations differ or stray.